# Organising resources for an Android project into multiple packages

Tags: android, android-resources, eclipse-adt

I'm working on an Android project using Eclipse. The project contains multiple modules connecting to a central core, and it would make sense to organise them into subpackages, e.g.

`com.example.myapp` -- containing core classes and activities

`com.example.myapp.module1` -- classes and activities pertaining to module 1

`com.example.myapp.module2` -- classes and activities pertaining to module 2

and so on. Since each module cannot work independently, everything is included in a single Eclipse project.

Now, it would be great to organise the resources into separate packages as well. At the moment all of my layouts and drawables are precompiled into `com.example.myapp.R`.

Is there any way to organise the project so that Eclipse would automatically put resources for module 1 into `com.example.myapp.module1.R` etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.example.myapp.module2.SomeClass` are Java package names and you can freely choose them for every class. You don't even need to start with `com.example.myapp`.

But `com.example.myapp.R` is generated from the package name defined in your `AndroidManifest.xml` and that is fixed since that package name identifies your app and resources belong to the app. There is as far as I know no way to split that somehow into further packages (if you keep it in one project).

However if you use [library projects](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects) to include in your app it might be possible that you can have different `.R`s.